# Excel VBA macro for VLOOKUP between workbooks only when lookup_value contains a value

Tags: excel, vba

I am new to vba, so please excuse my rookie mistakes.

I am assuming that the user has open the workbook containing the values to be looked up (Mating connectors in this case).  I want to prompt them to open the workbook for which they want to add columns containing the mating connectors.  The biggest problem I'm having with the code below is that it is inserting the vlookup even if the row is blank all the way to the limit of the spreadsheet (1,048,576 rows!).  I would like to only add the vlookup if the row contains a value in column E.

I also would like to make the worksheets in the vlookup not be hard coded to a specific sheet.  I tried creating variables to accomplish this, but I cannot find the syntax to use them in the vlookup.

Thanks in advance!

```
Sub Mate_OPEN_WKBOOK()

Dim xFileName As Variant
Dim xSourceSh As Worksheet
Dim xSourceWb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet

MsgBox "Please open the workbook which you want to add mates to"
xFileName = Application.GetOpenFilename("Excel Files (*.xl*), *.xls", 1, "Open the workbook")
If xFileName = False Then Exit Sub
Set xSourceWb = Workbooks.Open(xFileName)
Set xSourceSh = xSourceWb.Worksheets.Item(1)
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("List")

With xSourceSh
    Range("F:F").Formula = "=VLOOKUP('Lines'!B:B,'[Connector Mates SEARCH.XLS]List'!A:F,6,FALSE)"
    Range("G:G").Formula = "=VLOOKUP('Lines'!B:B,'[Connector Mates SEARCH.XLS]List'!A:F,4,FALSE)"

End Sub
```

Comment: Link to the other workbook (https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=_YgCJb2FF-4) and run your lookup over the link?

Comment: What version of Excel do you have?